# WPF Data Triggers and Changing the Style of the Control

Tags: wpf, datatrigger

I am using my custom validation engine to validate my ViewModel properties. I am stuck at the last step. I want to change the background color of the `TextBox` when the validation fails. So, I implemented `DataTrigger`s and binded it to the HasError property. HasError is a normal CLR property.

```
  public bool HasError
        {
            get
            {
                var hasError = Errors.Count() > 0;
                return hasError;
            }
        }
```

And here is the code:

```
 <Style x:Key="textBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">                   

            <Style.Triggers>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=HasError}" Value="True">

                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>          


            </Style.Triggers>

        </Style>
```

The problem is that it will be fired only once when the `this.DataContext` is assigned to a view model. So, I thought maybe I can use Dependency Property instead of the normal property but that did not worked out either.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

It seems like the `DataTrigger`s are only fired when hooked to the CLR properties and not the dependency properties.

**UPDATE 2:**

If only the following code worked:

```
 ****<Trigger Property="{Binding Path=HasError}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </Trigger>****
```

**UPDATE 3 WORKING:**

As the answer mentioned I had to fire the `INotifyPropertyChanged` event.

> public
>   ObservableCollection
>   Errors
>           {
>               get { return (ObservableCollection)GetValue(ErrorsProperty);
>   }
>               set
>               {
>                   SetValue(ErrorsProperty, value);
>
> ```
>             OnPropertyChanged("HasError");
>
>         }
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF system will never know that your `HasError` property changed, that's why it only fires once. One of the methods to accomplish this is implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` and firing `PropertyChanged` events when the collection of errors changes.

Comment: Oh you are a savior! Thanks a million. I have updated the code to reflect the changes.

Comment: Ah found a bug in my code. All the properties are dependent on the Errors collection. Which means all the colored red if there is a single entry in errors collection.